# How would I finish this java code?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

(This is for a project, so yes it is homework)

The task is to create arrays using user input (which I was able to do), then for the second part, use a separate method to sort the array in ascending order then output it. I have gotten it to do everything I need except I don't know how I would get it to sort. The directions say to use a while loop from 0 to the length to find the minimum value then swap that with the 1st, but I don't know how to do this. This is what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int storage = getNumDigits(in);
    if(storage == 0){
        System.out.print("No digits to store? OK, goodbye!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    int []a = new int [storage];
    a = getDigits(a, in);
    displayDigits(a);
    selectionSort(a);
}

private static int getNumDigits(Scanner inScanner) {
    System.out.print("Please enter the number of digits to be stored: ");
    int stored = inScanner.nextInt();
        while(stored < 0){
        System.out.println("ERROR! You must enter a non-negative number of digits!");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Please enter the number of digits to be stored: ");
        stored = inScanner.nextInt();
        }
    return stored;
}

private static int[] getDigits(int[] digits, Scanner inScanner) {
    int length = digits.length;
    int count = 0; 
    int toBeStored = 0;
    while(count < length){
    System.out.print("Enter integer " +count +": ");
    toBeStored = inScanner.nextInt();
    digits[count] = toBeStored;
    count++;
    }
    return digits;
}

private static void displayDigits(int[] digits) {
    int len = digits.length;
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Array before sorting:");
    System.out.println("Number of digits in array: " +len);
    System.out.print("Digits in array: ");
    for(int cnt = 0; cnt < len-1; cnt++){
        System.out.print(digits[cnt] + ", ");
    }
    System.out.println(digits[len-1]);
}

private static void selectionSort(int[] digits) {
    int l = digits.length;
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Array after sorting:");
    System.out.println("Number of digits in array: " +l);
    System.out.print("Digits in array: ");
    int index = 0;
    int value = digits[0];
    int indVal = digits[index];
    while(index < l){
        indVal = digits[index];
        if(indVal <= value){
            indVal = value;
            digits[index] = value;
            index++;
        }
        else if(value < indVal){
            index++;
        }
        System.out.print(value);
        //This is where I don't know what to do.
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at Arrays.sort. Or just do a simple bubble sort

Comment: Do a google search for bubble sort

Comment: It may be easier to visualize the task at hand before jumping directly into the code. I had used a pen and pad to help with my coding assignments, so I may recommend doing so as well.

Comment: So your specific minimum example is the `selectionSort()` method. Guys no, the directions are right there.

Comment: If you write it in a professional fashion, you don't need to put the "homework" banner: http://sscce.org and Jon Skeet's perfect question link at [ask]

Comment: It looks like you need to store the index of max. element, not the element itself. Then swap using array assignment and a temporary value. Let us know if still stuck after looking up selection sort.

Comment: @MiJyn Doubtful. The linked question asks about dealing with case insensitivity, whereas this question doesn't talk about that at all.

Comment: @DennisMeng I'm so sorry, I meant that for another question entirely

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're asked to write [selection sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort).  It's a simple O(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithm.  All you need are two for loops.  For each iteration of the outer for loop, the inner for loop searches through the unsorted portion of the list and finds the minimum element.  As you can see, the minimum element is swapped with the first element in the unsorted part of the list.

[image: Selection sort]

Comment: @DennisMeng I find that gifs are really good at showing people how sorting algorithms work. Plus it's just cool to watch :)

Comment: Agreed. It would've been nice to have something this awesome to work with when I was learning sorting algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

- Start by assuming the first item in the array is the smallest.
- You'll want to keep track of it's value and its position in the array.
- Then you'll want to iterate through the rest of the array looking for a smaller item.
- Once you know the index of the smallest item, it's just a simple matter of swapping the two:

  temp = array[0];

  array[0] = array[indx];

  array[indx] = temp;

Answer (score 0):

The method name you mentioned is **selectionSort**, I think you should use selection sort code here.

private static void selectionSort(int[] digits) {
        int len = digits.length;

```
    /* Selection sort starts */
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {   
        int min = i;   
        for (int j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {   
            if (digits[j]<digits[min]) {   
                min = j;   
            }   
        }   
        /**
         * Swap data
         */
        int temp = digits[i];
        digits[i] = digits[min];
        digits[min] = temp;
    } 

    /* Selection sort ends */

    /* Print necessary information here */
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Array after sorting:");
    System.out.println("Number of digits in array: " +len);
    System.out.print("Digits in array: ");
   /* Print digit  */ 
    for(int cnt = 0; cnt < len-1; cnt++){
        System.out.print(digits[cnt] + ", ");
    }
    System.out.println(digits[len-1]);
}
```

Above is an example, but you'd better put the logic for printing array information after sorting out of the method selectionSort, since this method should be used only for sorting not printing..